# is the Office 365 Management API restricted by an E? licence?

Tags: office365

When I try to consent the ActivityFeed.Read permission I'm getting:

Could not grant admin consent. Your organization does not have a subscription (or service principal) for the following API(s):  [BUT5Ua6QwGA9Zk7lhfWvgw]

Tried creating an app registration with the above mentioned permission